# DIdn't get the lost reputation when the downvoted answer is deleted

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers, voting, down-votes

Today I saw this [Error converting NSString to UTF8String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335137/error-converting-nsstring-to-utf8string/17335280#17335280) question on Stack Overflow. There were some incorrect answers. I down-voted them all. I lost some points too (I  know down-voting answer will cost -1 Rep). Later these answers were deleted. But till now I didn't get the lost reputation back.

> [image: Reputation Change]

In previous times, I got the lost reputation when a down-voted answer was deleted, but today it not. Is there any change in the down-vote reputation scheme ? Or is that a bug ?

Comment: Did you look on your reputation tab? When  were they removed?

Comment: It took about 40 minutes yesterday... how long have you waited since the answeres were deleted?

Comment: For some reason this is a corner case that does not cause auto recalc like all other events, think it was reported somewhere. If you will perform any other action like posting or downvoting you will most likely see those points back.

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and click on `Trigger Reputation Recalc`. You will get your reputations back. But you can do this once a day.

Comment: @Bart: It was deleted almost 1.45 Hr ago.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: It was deleted almost 1.45 Hr ago.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I did all that. Refreshed but didn't worked. but the link provided by hims056 worked.

Comment: @hims056: Thanks for the tip, it worked :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard This happened to me today. Would this be a bug or a feature request?

Comment: @Troyen give it another day then submit a bug report as things have changed and we can no longer do a recalc manually.